# How to make one string out of three variables?

Tags: cobol

I want to make three fields into one field with only a single space between each word in Cobol. I this the correct format below

```
  STRING SORT-WORKER-LAST  SPACE       
         SORT-WORKER-FIRST SPACE       
         SORT-WORKER-MID   SPACE       
       DELIMITED BY SIZE               
         INTO REC-VSAM-NAME
```

This didn't work:

```
   STRING SORT-WORKER-LAST  SPACE       
          SORT-WORKER-FIRST SPACE       
          SORT-WORKER-MID   SPACE       
       DELIMITED BY space              
         INTO REC-VSAM-NAME        

   STRING SORT-WORKER-LAST         
          SORT-WORKER-FIRST        
          SORT-WORKER-MID          
       DELIMITED BY space              
         INTO REC-VSAM-NAME
```

Not working either.

```
      SS5726    test                test           t

     " " DELIMETED BY SPACE
```

This above code is not giving me what I am looking for either.

Comment: I ran the code an neither of the formats above work. I am running the example now at work.  I want one space between the names TEST TEST T

Comment: These are names. STRING will not give you correct results if you can have embedded spaces. `JOAO MARIA DE SOUSA`. The thing to do is to write a little program to check your data. You may get lucky, but names have a habit of not just rolling over and cooperating. Depends on the source, and whether they have been "cleaned" in your system. Simple typo can get a space anywhere, remember, if allowed by the system. Also bear in mind that you may blow the length of your output, so you should check for that.

Comment: There are no embedded spaces. I have it working now. I mistook the " " SPACE DELIMITED BY SIZE as a single parameter and only put that in at the end. Once I realized that this was an actual parameter of its own it now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used in a STRING statement, the figurative constant SPACE (or SPACES, they are equivalent, the plural means nothing except for human reading) has a length of one byte.

You may not be finished with this. If your source fields contain embedded spaces, you will be best to abandon STRING and do something else.

If you proceed with STRING or there is another time you want to consider using it, then you also have to think about the length of your output field. If you don't do anything about it, it will be quietly truncated.

I've included an example of how to do something. Note that the STRING now has a conditional element (ON), so you must delimit the scope of the STRING by END-STRING (also possible, but tacky, with full-stop/period).

If, logically, the output cannot be breached, the ON OVERFLOW is not needed. Also, if what you are told to do is "just truncate" then it can be omitted, although I'd tend to at least count them, and display the count at the end of the program. Then when the Analyst has said, "there won't be any, just truncate if there are" you can go back and say that there were 3,931 when you did your volume test.

As ScottNelson has pointed out in a comment, there are a couple of things to watch out for with STRING. What concerns you here is that only the data selected by the STRING will appear in your output field, your output field will *not* be space-padded, as it would be after a MOVE statement.

Because you have been using fixed-length fields up to now, you won't have noticed this. Once you have the correction, you may find, if you are not setting the output field to SPACE first, that you have a mixture of values, with some left over from the previous content.

Another one with STRING is the POINTER.

The effects of the way STRING works is useful if that is what you want. You just have to know what to do to avoid those things when you don't want that action.

Every time you find something new in COBOL, hit that manual. Language Reference first. Try to understand. Programming Guide. Try further. If unsure, experiment. Read manual. Experiment. Continue until understood.

Each time I read the manual, I try to look at something else as well. One technique with knowing a language is to know the type of thing that can be done, and to know where to find the detail, and how to understand the explanations.

You will find similar things with all the "complex" COBOL verbs, STRING, UNSTRING, INSPECT. They have actions which seem initially to be working against you, but which are useful, and otherwise not available, when you need them.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION. 
   PROGRAM-ID. DOUGH. 
   DATA DIVISION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  PART-1 PIC X(30) VALUE "TEST". 
   01  PART-2 PIC X(30) VALUE "TEST". 
   01  PART-3 PIC X(30) VALUE "T". 
   01  ALL-PARTS PIC X(30). 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
       MOVE SPACE TO ALL-PARTS
  *    MOVE ZERO TO data-name-used-with-POINTER
  *    (if used)                                 
       STRING PART-1 DELIMITED BY SPACE 
              SPACE DELIMITED BY SIZE 
              PART-2 DELIMITED BY SPACE 
              SPACE DELIMITED BY SIZE 
              PART-3 DELIMITED BY SPACE 
         INTO ALL-PARTS 
         ON OVERFLOW 
           DISPLAY "SORRY, YOUR DATA WAS TRUNCATED"
       END-STRING 

       DISPLAY 
             ">" 
                ALL-PARTS 
             "<" 
       GOBACK 
       .
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can the over flow be something other than a display can you put several lings of code in there if you wanted to. I would imagine that it works similar to that of a try-catch in a modern language.

Comment: @DougHauf there is no real limit to the amount of code you can put within the scope of the ON OVERFLOW. Personally, I'd set a flag and test it afterwards if there was going to be business logic involved. I don't know enough about a try-catch to answer definitively, but I'd doubt they were similar. ON is "when this is true at this particular point, and no other, do this". The scope of ON itself can also be limited by NOT ON, similar in style to the READ, but the NOT ON would have to be then limited by the end-of-scope END-STRING. Scope in COBOL may not be what you understand as scope elsewhere.

Comment: Don't forget to `MOVE SPACES TO ALL-PARTS` before the `STRING` statement, because the `STRING` statement does not space fill the result field.

Comment: @ScottNelson good point. I was assuming that was already done. Just realised now that you've pointed it out, it wouldn't show up, because the length of the STRING in question was effectively fixed, so would always overwrite all of what was there. And now it won't... hitting the edit shortly. Thanks.

Comment: I have question Bill. have you used natural programming language all that much. I need to take a dob 20140630 and flip it around so that it is mm dd yyyy. Is there a way to pull different positions off of the day in natural like in Cobol.

Comment: In your answer to the Natural question the other day, you mentioned the `SUBSTRING` version of the `MOVE`. I think that would do it. Questions should be asked as Questions though :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try....

```
STRING SORT-WORKER-LAST DELIMITED BY SPACE
       " " DELIMITED BY SIZE
       SORT-WORKER-FIRST DELIMITED BY SPACE
       " " DELIMITED BY SIZE
       SORT-WORKER-MID DELIMITED BY SPACE
  INTO REC-VSAM-NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
STRING
    field-1 DELIMITED BY SIZE
    " " DELIMITED BY SIZE
    field-2 DELIMITED BY SIZE
  INTO big-field
```

Comment: No Brian. Good moment for TRIM, perhaps, but we don't have it on the Mainframe, which Doug is using.

Comment: No way.  :-)  (On TRIM that is).   Thanks for the heads up Bill.  And yeah, having looked again.  Bad advice, wrong advice.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of this one without looking at it :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/13980135/1927206

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness sake, you can do the following if you want to be able to cope with data fields that have embedded spaces (in other words, text fields containing multiple words):

```
INSPECT SORT-WORKER-FIRST
        REPLACING TRAILING SPACES BY LOW-VALUES.
INSPECT SORT-WORKER-MID
        REPLACING TRAILING SPACES BY LOW-VALUES.
INSPECT SORT-WORKER-LAST
        REPLACING TRAILING SPACES BY LOW-VALUES.
STRING SORT-WORKER-LAST " " SORT-WORKER-FIRST " " SORT-WORKER-MID
       DELIMITED BY LOW-VALUE INTO REC-VSAM-NAME.
```

For instance, this would cope when `SORT-WORKER-LAST` contained something like "VAN DYKE".

If you didn't want to modify the existing `SORT-WORKER-*` fields, you'd have to move each to a separate field and `INSPECT` and then `STRING` those fields.

What you are doing here is converting each of the strings to the 'C' equivalent - terminated by a NUL.

Of course, this depends if your Cobol is new enough.